# How to get svg from MDL working with webpack

Tags: css, svg, npm, sass, webpack

Using a checkbox component form Material Design Lite, i.e.
https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/checkbox

the tickmark.svg is not shown properly when I use

```
import '../../node_modules/material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite.scss';
```

for bundling with npm and webpack. Instead of:

[image]

I get:

[image]

In the browser I find the following path to tickmark.svg which is the svg that is 'missing':

[image]

When using either one of these two alternatives it works as it should:
1) `import '../../node_modules/material-design-lite/.tmp/material-design-lite.css';`
2) `import '../../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css';`

To compare, when using 2 I get following in the browser:

[image]

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var Clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var bootstrapPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css');
var sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'assets');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        './assets/js/index' // entry point of our app. .assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    }
    ,
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty'
    }
    ,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('Pqbq Banner!!!! todo'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/assets/index.tmpl.html'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new Clean(['assets/bundles'])
    ],
    module: {
        preloaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                loader: 'eslint'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js[x]?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower-components)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/mapbox-gl/js/render/shaders.js'),
                loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/webworkify/index.js'),
                loader: 'worker'
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.css$/,
            //     loader: 'style!css?modules!postcss'
            // },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
            },
            // {test: /\.(woff2?|svg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000'},
            // {test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            //   {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
            {test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=8192!svgo'},
        ]
    }
    ,
    postcss: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components', bootstrapPath, sourcePath],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        alias: {
            webworkify: 'webworkify-webpack',
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }
    }
    ,
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './assets',
        colors: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue completely, but one part of the problem is that the actual url is `.svg?embed` which won't match your `test` regex. I am seeing the same problem. Try using `/\.svg(\?embed)?$/`

Comment: @pho3nixf1re Good point! I tried, but problem remains (same console output). Does this regex indeed catch it correctly?

Comment: @pho3nixf1re I checked you regex and that should indeed catch '.svg?embed'. Please let me know if you find further progress in solving this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to override the $image_path variable by creating my own material.scss file.  I grabbed this file:

https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/material-design-lite.scss

and then added:

```
@import "./variables";
```

at the top.

In that file I added this line:

```
$image_path: '~material-design-lite/dist/images/' !default;
```